# How to query database in WordPress and loop through results

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've been used to making simple PDO queries to MySQL like this:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `my_table` ORDER BY `rank`");
$query->execute();
$numrows = $query->rowCount();
while($row = $query->fetch()) {
$ThisColumn = $row['value'];
}
```

But I want to do the same using WordPress (not to one of WordPress's own tables, but to one of my own).  What is the simplest way of translating the query?

Comment: Read the docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: That's where I came from.  Thanks for the 'aha' moment.

Comment: If that's where you came from, why aren't you asking a specific question about what you read there? Or at least show that you've made an attempt to write your own code?

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT * FROM `my_table` ORDER BY `rank`";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
foreach ($result as $instance) {
echo $instance->value;
}
```